# PHP - Accept various date formats for input and output date

Tags: php

I have a massive excel file im importing and storing to a date field (date("Y-m-d")).
Problem is, the input is in several different formats, examples:

```
1) 2015/01/01 // valid format, php converts this to yyyy-mm-dd
2) 2015-01 // supposed to be 2015-01-01
3) jan/18 // supposed to be 2018-01-01
```

As you see, while most are supplied in valid formats, there are (mostly) two other formats used being "year-month" and "month/year".
Everything indicates strtotime, and the below should work - but how would I indicate the 'first day' of the month when the day isnt supplied (because otherwise it would just end up being null for everything but (1) above if my understanding is correct)?

```
//assumes $str is one of the above mentioned formats
if (($timestamp = strtotime($str)) === false) {
    $date = null;
} else {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: You need to use preg_match with regex for each case and apply modification case by case

Comment: regular expression is the way (need to find patters) its not that hard in your problem

Comment: Do you know all the date formats?

Comment: just the 3 listed above @Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create format functions based on the length of the input date strings.

```
$formats = [
    10 => function($string) { return date_create_from_format('Y/m/d', $string); },
    7 => function($string) { return date_create_from_format('Y-m j', $string . ' 1'); },
    6 => function($string) { return date_create_from_format('M/y j', $string . ' 1'); }
];
```

Then create your dates using those functions

```
$date = $formats[strlen($a_date_string)]($a_date_string);
```

I appended 1 to the strings in the format functions to set the date to the first day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script similar to this and run it multiple times adjusting it until you get all the date formats.

```
// should be listed from more specific to least specific date format
$dateFormats = [
    'Y/m/d' => ['midnight'],
    'Y-m'   => ['midnight', 'first day of this month'],
    'M/y'   => ['midnight', 'first day of this month'],
];

$dates = [
    '2015/01/01',
    '2015-01',
    'jan/18',
];

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    if ($dateTime = getDateTimeFrom($date, $dateFormats)) {
        echo "{$dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')} \n";
    } else {
        echo "Unknown date format : {$date} \n";
    }
}


function getDateTimeFrom(string $dateString, array $dateFormats) : ?\DateTime {
    if (!$dateString) {
        return null;
    }

    foreach ($dateFormats as $format => $modifiers) {
        if ($dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dateString)) {
            foreach ($modifiers as $modification) {
                $dateTime->modify($modification);
            }

            return $dateTime;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

// Outputs:
// 2015-01-01 00:00:00 
// 2015-01-01 00:00:00 
// 2018-01-01 00:00:00
```